# strange result of procedure with sql select in python

Tags: python, mysql, pymysql

I have created database and table on it with information about software versions, url for seeking updates, etc.
I need to get info from this database by python.
I have created procedure:

```
def getserverver(name):
    connection = pymysql.connect(host='localhost',
                             user='root',
                             password='mysql',
                             db='softupdates',
                             charset='utf8',
                             cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
     sql = "SELECT Name FROM softupdates.soft where Name like name"
     cursor.execute(sql)
     result = cursor.fetchone()
    return result
```

And use it after:

```
panorama12onserver = (getserverver('Профессиональная ГИС %Панорама %версия 12%x64%'))['Name']
panorama11onserver = (getserverver('Профессиональная ГИС %Карта 2011%'))['Name']
panedit11onserver = (getserverver('Профессиональный векторизатор %Панорама-редактор%версия 11%'))['Name']
panedit12onserver = (getserverver('Профессиональный векторизатор %Панорама-редактор%версия 12%x64%'))['Name']
print (panorama12onserver)
print (panorama11onserver)
print (panedit12onserver)
print (panedit11onserver)
```

Why did i get the result like this:

```
Профессиональная ГИС "Карта 2011" (версия 11.13.5.7)
Профессиональная ГИС "Карта 2011" (версия 11.13.5.7)
Профессиональная ГИС "Карта 2011" (версия 11.13.5.7)
Профессиональная ГИС "Карта 2011" (версия 11.13.5.7)
```

The same data on every string, but it is not in database like this. What am I doing wrong (besides stripting =))?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Beause you are executing the same query over and over again. Try changing to

```
 sql = "SELECT Name FROM softupdates.soft where Name like %s"
 cursor.execute(sql, (name,))
```

And you don't need to open a connection every time inside `getserverver` open it once (outside that function scope) and reuse it. Opening a database connection is a costly operation.

having fixed the original problem with this code, if you are worndering why you are not seeing a dictionary, well that's not how you are printing it!!

```
(getserverver('Профессиональный векторизатор %Панорама-редактор%версия 12%x64%'))['Name']
```

This returns a scalar value and not a dictionary.

Comment: @ e4c5 Yes, you are ritght, thank you. But why now function return not dictionary as result?

Comment: That's a different question. I have i believe correctly answered the original question. However please do see the update for the issue you raised via a comment. If you have any other questions, please post a new question.